# unable to print one pdf fonts text to another pdf?

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext

I have pdf in [telufu pdf](http://anils.com/DraftRolls/PDFGeneration.aspx?urlPath=D%3a%5C%5CSSR_2013_FINAL%20ROLLS%5C%5CAC_238%5C%5CTelugu%5C%5CS01A238P038.PDF) (replace anils.com with  123.176.47.55) I want extract some text from that pdf (like in that pdf page no 3 firtst block data I need to read) for that I download all fonts for that page using [mupdf-1.3-windows](http://code.google.com/p/mupdf/downloads/detail?name=mupdf-1.3-windows.zip&can=2&q=OpSys=Windows)

it downloads all fonts that pdf uses but when I write that text by using those fonts to another pdf some of the texts not  redered the code is like

```
//output file name
public static String pdf1 = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\itextpdf\\anil.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new URL("http://anils/DraftRolls/PDFGeneration.aspx?urlPath=D%3a\\SSR_2013_FINAL+ROLLS\\AC_238\\Telugu\\S01A238P038.PDF"),null);
        System.out.println("This PDF has "+reader.getNumberOfPages()+" pages.");

        // reading page no 3 
        String page = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 3);                     

        // all fonts I had checked total of 7 fonts but I didn't get all the fonts 
        BaseFont f = BaseFont.createFont("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\itextpdf\\fonts\\AAAAAD+Gautami-0174.ttf", "", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font telugu = new Font(f, 18.0f, Font.BOLD);

        Paragraph description = new Paragraph(page,telugu);

        // description.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER); 

        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdf1));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        document.add(description);
        document.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

some of the text never matched for any font how to solve this?

Comment: Your code already tells you what you're doing wrong: you're using the `PdfTextExtractor` to extract plain text (no styles, no fonts,...). You're not using `PdfCopy` or `PdfStamper` to deal with the actual PDF content (including font dictionaries, annotations,...).

Comment: is it  possible to convert that pdf fonts and styles to html text with same fonts and styles

Comment: That's very hard to do. Especially if your PDF isn't tagged. Before anyone can answer that question, you need to tell us: is your PDF tagged? (If not: forget about conversion to HTML.)

Comment: what was the possible solutions for my queries?

Comment: If a PDF isn't taggedm you're out of luck. Where you see a table with the human eye, a machine only sees snippets of text and lines. Without the proper tags, a machine can't *see* any table. The same goes more or less for styles. There is no such thing as a <b> or an <i> tag in PDF. There are only different fonts such as Helvetica Bold and Helvetica Italic, but you can't always tell if a font is bold or italic based on the name that is used for that font. Long story short: forget about your requirement. You're asking for something that is extremely difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: <font face="TL_TTHemalatha" style="font-size:18pt;font-style:Bold"> Fn~ÉÜ[ JÈÁLýRi ÇØÕÁ»y c 2013</font> i get this type of code in that pdf ,based on this i can able to build html , idid it using jpedal

Comment: but the problem is how to get that TL_TTHemalatha  exactely what they used for pdf generation

Comment: [pdf link](http://123.176.47.55/DraftRolls/PDFGeneration.aspx?urlPath=D%3a\\SSR_2013_FINAL+ROLLS\\AC_238\\Telugu\\S01A238P038.PDF) check this pdf once

Comment: @Bruno   i have a font data  like FontFile2 = 152 0 R i have that stream can i get glyphs from this stream

Comment: You're not supposed to do that. Please don't try making me an accomplice.

Comment: sorry , all people say harder no one says impossible thats way i am asking

Comment: Would it be okay to have the text organized just like in the original? Or is there a need to reflow it?

Comment: original text is enough

Comment: And the data to extract, *like in that pdf page no 3 firtst block data i need to read*, are known by their coordinates or by what kind of description?

Comment: means  i need visible text of pdf , no need of  coordinates i can use regular expression , and it is not possible to get visible text from this pdf so want to get ttf files like aaaad+gauthami

Answer (score 0):

I think it is too hard to do it natively.

You should convert it to an another format, preferably text-based.

I often need to extract vectorial schemas, and I personally use svg for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention in the comments to the original question that the text may be organized just like in the original, that there is no need to reflow it, importing the original page as a template and only showing selected areas may be a solution for your needs:

```
public void testImportFragment() throws IOException, DocumentException
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new URL("http://anils/DraftRolls/PDFGeneration.aspx?urlPath=D%3a\\SSR_2013_FINAL+ROLLS\\AC_238\\Telugu\\S01A238P038.PDF"),null);
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\itextpdf\\anil.pdf"));
    document.open();
    document.newPage();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Test importing the contents of the first row of page three in a different order."));
    copyFragment(reader, writer);
    document.close();
    reader.close();
}

public void copyFragment(PdfReader source, PdfWriter target) throws DocumentException
{
    PdfImportedPage page = target.getImportedPage(source, 3);
    PdfContentByte directContent = target.getDirectContent();

    PdfTemplate template = directContent.createTemplate(110, 57);
    template.addTemplate(page, 1, 0, 0, 1, -15, -706);
    directContent.addTemplate(template, 200, 700);

    template = directContent.createTemplate(110, 57);
    template.addTemplate(page, 1, 0, 0, 1, -202, -705);
    directContent.addTemplate(template, 200, 600);

    template = directContent.createTemplate(110, 57);
    template.addTemplate(page, 1, 0, 0, 1, -389, -705);
    directContent.addTemplate(template, 200, 500);
}
```